# Do targets of pattern matching in F# have to be always comma separated?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching

So I was looking at the following bit of code

```
let rec zip list list' =
  match list, list' with
  | [], _ -> []
  | _, [] -> []
  | h::t, h'::t' -> (h, h')::(zip t t')
```

when I noticed that it is not a syntactic error to replace

```
match list, list' with
```

by

```
  match list list' with
```

being the only error shown

```
This expression was expected to have type
    'a -> 'b list * 'c list    
but here has type
    'b list
```

on `zip t t'` (over `t`).

My question is if makes any sense, at all, to have `match list list' with` instead of `match list list' with`. Shouldn't the targets of pattern matching be always comma separated?

Comment: I would think that the compiler now think's you're trying to call a function named list with the parameter list' and pattern matching on the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but if you write `match list list' with` there is only a *single* target, said target being what you get from applying the function `list` to the argument `list'`. Since `list` isn't actually a function, you get the type error you quote.

Comment: Ah! I hadn't thought of that possibility. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, extrapolating from the error message, is looks as if there is only _ever_ a single target; it's just that this target (and the corresponding patterns) may be a tuple, and apparently F# allows tuples to be written with just commas and no enclosing parentheses as long as it's otherwise delimited in the syntax. Milner's original ML did this too.

Comment: Pretty much the only thing commas ever do in F# is delimit/create tuples. Coming from C#, it was a bit of a revelation for me when I figured that out.